# C# How to use a value of the variable from the loop outside of the loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio, loops, variables, nmea

I'm trying to calculate the NMEA checksum based on the string, so I can compare it with the given checksum and declare wether the string has error in it or not. 
Here's the way I'm trying to do it (the given index of 0 is just an example for a single line)

```
        List<string> richTextBoxLines = richTextBox1.Lines.ToList();
        richTextBoxLines.RemoveAll(x => !x.Contains("GPGGA"));

        richTextBox1.Lines = richTextBoxLines.ToArray();
        NOLbox.Text = richTextBox1.Lines.Count().ToString();

        int finalCheckSum = 0;
        string sumOfBytes = richTextBox1.Lines[0].Split('*').First().Substring(1);
        for (int i = 0; i == sumOfBytes.Length; i++)
            { 
            finalCheckSum ^= Convert.ToByte(sumOfBytes[i]);
            }
        checksumValue.Text = finalCheckSum.ToString();
```

The first part removes communicates other than GGA, and the the rest of it has to calculate the checksum.
The thing is I'm going to need the `FinalCheckSum` variable value outside of the loop, and so far it returns 0 - because it is declared as a 0 of course, althought declaring it within the loop is pointless. That given, how can I get the variable value outside of the loop so I can use it later on?

Comment: because of this `i == sumOfBytes.Length` I doubt your loop is ever running. I guess you want `i <= sumOfBytes.Length`

Comment: `i < sumOfBytes.Length` would be correct. `<=` will give an `IndexOutOfRangeException`

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I've had `IndexOutOfRangeException` with `<=`. Now, with `<` it works well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The general solution for this is to move the variable you need 1 level upper in the scope, until it is accessible where you need it. In your case, I see you already did that, your variable is declared before the for loop. The error must be on the loop's stop condition. I think you meant to write something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= sumOfBytes.Length; i++)
```